# Cannot set ACL permission at Samba share

Tags: linux, samba, access-control-list, samba4, attributes

I have setup samba share at xfs file system. Samba 4.2 runs at CentOS 7.

Setting POSIX ACLs and extended attributes works as expected (`setfacl -m user:joe:rw example.txt`, `setfattr -n user.example -v foo example.txt`) at Linux.

The samba sharing is defined in `smb.conf`:

```
[public]
    comment = Public Stuff
    path = /home/samba
    public = yes
    writable = yes
    printable = no
    valid users = @staff
    nt acl support = yes
    vfs objects = acl_xattr
```

**Edit**: added these two options:

```
    map acl inherit = yes
    store dos attributes = yes
```

I'm able to connect to the sharing 'public'. I'm able to create files and directories. I'm able to set permissions mapped to UNIX permissions, but I'm not able to set ACL permissions to other users. When I'm logged to sharing public as user john and I want to add extra access permission for user e.g. joe, then Windows says that Object joe was not found. I use Windows 10. There are no errors logs (`/var/log/samba/*`).

**Edit**: problem solved. I forgot to add samba password also for other users using: `smbpasswd -a joe`.

Comment: does [this](https://serverfault.com/a/759722/168178) help?

Comment: When I added options: `map acl inherit = yes` and `store dos attributes = yes`, then permissions are saved in POSIX ACLs an extended attributes, but I'm still not able to add ACLs to other users.